# cannot find package "golang.org/x/sys/unix" in any of: $GOROOT $GOPATH

Tags: go

My terminal was yelling at me because, it has some missing packages:

```sh
 cannot find package "golang.org/x/sys/unix" in any of: $GOROOT $GOPATH
```

Maybe a silly question but I think it deserves to be here.

Comment: Try to check the latest version of Go. I had similiar issue, and updating to Go 1.14 solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [@PeggyTsai](https://twitter.com/zxc1788fc)

[Let us gets the packages](https://medium.com/@peggy_tsai/golang-go-build-show-cannot-find-package-golang-org-x-sys-unix-error-message-a8173399092a):

```golang
go get golang.org/x/sys/unix
```